# Basic of XLL Excel Addin - Need to invoke a C# API from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-interop, xll

I am quite new to creating excel addins.

Earlier I used to create a tlb for .NET libraries. I used to make my .NET class COMVISIBLE and create a Com callable wrapper and register as a tlb to call from Excel (using regasm).

I now have a math library written in C#. Got to know there is something called XLL and UDFs which I can use to invoke API's from the DLL. Little confused about XLA, XLL and UDFs. Not sure what should I do to call my API's.

Not sure where to get started. Any help would be helpful.

Thanks
Mani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [XLDNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/), [XLL+](http://www.planatechsolutions.com/main/default.htm), [Addin Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/), [VSTO](http://www.officezealot.com/vsto/Pages/index.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to take a look at http://nxll.codeplex.com too.

Comment: Guess this is for C++ code add-ins. I use C#.