# Copying/Mapping data between excel spread sheets, Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ado

I need to copy data using Vb.net if possible from one excel spreadworbook to another and place the data into the correct columns in the existing excel spreadsheet. The column titles of the spreadsheets match up, I have several templates I need to place data into and the order of the columns is different in each template so I need a way of searching for a column header in the template and then copying the data into that column.

Would the best way of achieving this using ADO?

For example move the data from this Workbook1 with columns "Test1", "Test2" and data

```
Test1   Test2
1         2
12        23
123       234
```

Into workbook 2 which will have the same column names but could be in a different order:

```
Test0   Test1   Test1.1  Test2
```

I need to do this automatically as I have alot of data to copy and 30-40 workbook templates to copy the data into, the templates columns are in different orders and can not be moved around.

Answer (score 0):

[There are different ways to interface with Excel using .NET.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852894/basic-of-xll-excel-addin-need-to-invoke-a-c-sharp-api-from-excel/7854055#7854055) If you are just looking to do it with one version of Excel, then [VSTO](http://www.officezealot.com/vsto/Pages/index.aspx) might be your easiest solution, otherwise use something else. I like to use [EXCEL-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/).

You can also use ADO to get the data out, but to put it in another one, I would think you would need one of the ways listed above to do it (since you would need to reference the excel object). If you are using Excel 2007 and above you can also directly access the XML files and manipulate them that way (minus xlb, of course).

You can also create a library from you execution file and copy it locally. [See here.](http://devcity.net/Articles/163/1/Articles.aspx)

As for headers, just use a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) or List(Of String) to figure out what the index of the file(s) is.